# How do you use the migration framework to add Django REST Framework Authentication Tokens

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-migrations, http-token-authentication

I am setting up a new API using the Django REST Framework, and I need to add Auth tokens to all the existing users. The docs say to do:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

for user in User.objects.all():
    Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
```

But ideally, this should happen using Django's new Migration Framework.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The trick here is knowing that `Token` uses a custom `save()` method to generate a unique `token.key` but that custom `save()` methods are not run inside migrations. So the first token will have a blank key and the second will fail with an `IntegrityError` because they key is also blank and not unique.

Instead, copy the `generate_key()` code into your migration like this:

```py
# Generated with `manage.py makemigrations --empty YOUR-APP`.

import binascii
import os

from django.db import migrations

# Copied from rest_framework/authtoken/models.py.
def generate_key():
    return binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(20)).decode()

def create_tokens(apps, schema_editor):
    User = apps.get_model('auth', 'User')
    Token = apps.get_model('authtoken', 'Token')
    for user in User.objects.filter(auth_token__isnull=True):
        token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user, key=generate_key())

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('YOUR-APP', 'YOUR-PREVIOUS-MIGRATION'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_tokens),
    ]
```

You should avoid importing the `rest_framework` code directly into a migration or one day your migrations will fail to run because you decided to remove rest_framework or the library's interface changed. Migrations need to be frozen in time.

Answer (score 2):

Start by creating an empty migration for the app you want it to be used with. In my case, I have an app called `users` where this kind of thing lives, so I ran:

```
manage.py makemigrations users --empty
```

That created a new file in my migrations directory that I was able to update with the following contents:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def add_tokens(apps, schema_editor):
    print "Adding auth tokens for the API..."
    for user in User.objects.all():
        Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

def remove_tokens(apps, schema_editor):
    print "Deleting all auth tokens for the API..."
    Token.objects.all().delete()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('users', '0002_load_initial_data'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(add_tokens, reverse_code=remove_tokens),
    ]
```

Comment: You shouldn't import code into a migration or one day in the future your migrations will start to fail after you decide to remove `rest_framework` or the `rest_framework` interface changes. Migrations need to stand completely alone.